# PHP throwing XDebug errors ONLY in command line mode

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php5, php.ini

I've been having a few problems running PHP-based utilities within the command line ever since I enabled the XDebug. It runs just fine when executing script through a browser, but once I try an execute a script on the command line, it throws the following errors:

```
h:\www\test>@php test.php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\development\xampplite\php\ext\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0

h:\www\test>
```

The script runs just fine after this, but it's something I can't seem to wrap my head around. Could it be a path issue within my php.ini config?  I'm not sure if that's the case considering it throws the same error no matter where I access the `@php` environmental variable.

Also, all paths within my php.ini are absolute. Not really sure what's going on here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think, you should check your Php.ini config, by default it's not on DEBUG mode, you havez to uncomment some lines, but I don't remember which line.